# Enigma 2 and arduino

Tags: python, arduino, ubuntu-12.04, enigma2

I'm newest with arduino i want to read informations from arduino and write it to  dream Box DM800 enigma 2.
i tried this code and it didn't work

```
    # Module de lecture/ecriture du port série
from serial import *
# Port série ttyACM0
# Vitesse de baud : 9600
# Timeout en lecture : 1 sec
# Timeout en écriture : 1 sec
with Serial(port="/dev/ttyACM0", baudrate=9600, timeout=1, writeTimeout=1) as port_serie:
    if port_serie.isOpen():
        while True:
            ligne = port_serie.read_line()
            print ligne
```

Can someone help me please

Comment: could you show the output?

Comment: In what way does it not work? Is an exception raised? Does nothing happen? Is there data available from /dev/ttyACM0, or is it blocked at `read_line()`? Are you sure that the port settings are 9600,8,N,1?

Comment: that's it I forgot to install pyserial